# How to hide '+' and '-' buttons from WatchKit slider?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, watchos

I want to show progress like slider bar given in native WatchKit.
But I want to hide + and - buttons.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

[image]

Comment: How about creating a custom slider?

Comment: that could be last way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer,

**Step 1:** Go to http://www.1x1px.me/ (Or any site where you can create image of 1Pixel)

**Step 2:** Choose any color and opacity 0, then download image

**step 3:** Use this image as **Min Image** and **Max Image** of slider.

Comment: In future versions they may add a feature to customize controls like sliders in WatchKit.